# How do I make compost?

Tags: compost

I have dried leaves, tons of dirt (seriously), and dead grass. How do I make compost?

I have tried to decompose the dry grass clippings and the leaves, but that did not work. I also researched this afterwards and apparently, you need to use some dirt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many many resources on the internet but you seem to have the ingredients necessary to start the process.  I would follow these basic steps

(1) take some dry woody branches and lay them down on soil to create the foundation.  This provides air to circulate from the bottom.

(2) On top of the branches, lay down alternate piles of dry leaves, grass clippings and soil.

(3) Water each layer if you are able to

(4) throw in some kitchen waste into the mix, if you have some.

Be patient because it does take time for this to work.  You will have to maintain the temperature of the pile so it does not get too hot or too cold.  Spray water as needed and turn the pile every few weeks to ensure that the outside part gets a chance to decompose inside the pile

Comment: Thanks - I knew that there were many resources online, but I wanted sort of like a 'first hand' how-to. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I'm fond of the in-ground composting "worm tube". You take length of PVC pipe, drill holes in a the lower section of it, and bury the lower portion. Then put your green and brown into it. The idea is that worms crawl in and out the holes, taking the nutrients with them. A sort of in-place vermiculture. I'm shocked at how quickly I can fill the tube and the materials in it collapse.

Here is a good reference. Mine are not nearly this tall, but still seem to work just fine.

http://offbeathome.com/worm-tube-composting/